# ¿Qué nombre se usa más comúnmente para referirse al dialecto mexicano del idioma español?

Tags: méxico, dialectos

En inglés, escribiríamos una cosa similar a "¿cuál es la palabra más común para [sustantivo] en español mexicano?" o escribiríamos "el dialecto mexicano del español"

Estoy principalmente interesado en aprender español mexicano en lugar del español como se habla en Espana. Donde vivo (en [El Estado de Colorado](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado)) el español mexicano es el dialecto más común.

Comment: Sorry, but this is complicated. The higher up the social ladder you go, the more the Spanish sounds like Spain structure-wise except for some word usages like we have with British English. Se puede decir el español mexicano, o hablado en Mexico. [instead of= en vez de]. What you get with Mexican terms are things like troca for truck or use of the madre as in: Me vale madres.

Answer (score 1):

Ni en inglés ni en español el castellano hablado en México es considerado un dialecto. Se lo suele denominar el “español de México” o más comúnmente el “acento mexicano”. La pregunta sería “¿cómo le dicen a la heladera (Argentinian for ‘fridge’) en México?” a la cual la respuesta sería “refrigerador”. En inglés tampoco se pregunta “what is the word for ‘nappy’ in the American dialect?” que es un error y la pregunta sería “what are ‘nappies’ called in the US?”, siendo la respuesta “diaper”.

Comment: It is quite common in the United States to ask somthing like, "what is the word for 'nappy' in  American English?" I see now that I should convert the noun "Mexico" into an adjective. "¿Cuál es la palabra para una diligencia impulsada por gasolina en español mexicano?" The key phrase is, "español mexicano"

Comment: No, ‘de México’ is entirely fine. Just skip the ‘dialect’ part

Comment: To be frank, I would think the following expression is more idiomatic: “Cómo le [dicen/llaman] en México a las heladeras?” (‘dicen’ is more common in Arg. and ‘llaman’ elsewhere). I don’t think I remember the last time I have used a phrase like “español colombiano” or “de Collombia. I would say instead say “en Colombia, las haches se pronuncian más suavemente”.

Comment: I agree with @MartinGeller, is more common in Latin America to day something like: 
"Cómo le [dicen/llaman] en México a los autobús?" or "Cómo le [dicen/llaman] a los autobús en México?"

Answer (score 0):

We can use the phrase, "Mexican Spanish" or "español mexicano".

Podemos escribir la pregunta de la siguiente manera:

> ¿Cuál es la palabra para "coche" en español mexicano?

La respuesta correcta es "carro". El siguiente excelente ejemplo proviene de [Martin Geller](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/33257/)

> ¿Cómo se dice "heladera" ("refrigerador" en Argentino) en español de México?”

Como tercer y último ejemplo podemos preguntar,

> "¿cuál es la palabra para 'pañal' en español mexicano?"

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment, I don’t remember the last time I have heard somebody use phrases like “español mexicano” or “español de Colombia”, but I have recently heard myself say  “en Bolivia, ‘mano’ puede ser masculino. Escuché a Evo Morález decir: ‘dame los manos’ en una entrevista”.

Answer (score 0):

Temas interesantes

En México se habla **el dialecto mexicano del español**. Actualmente en México, según el doctor Jaime Labastida, director de la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua, se hablan 68 lenguas indígenas con 264 variantes, siendo el español el vehículo de comunicación entre ellas y el nexo de unión entre los distintos pueblos.

> **In Mexico, the Mexican dialect of Spanish is spoken**. Currently in
> Mexico, according to Dr. Jaime Labastida, director of the Mexican
> Academy of Language, 68 indigenous languages with 264 variants are
> spoken, with Spanish being the vehicle of communication between them
> and the link between the different peoples.

LAS LENGUAS DE MEXICO
https://www.historiadelasinfonia.es/naciones/la-sinfonia-en-mexico/generalidades/las-lenguas-de-mexico/

---

*El español mexicano (o español de México, es-MX)2​ es la variedad de dialectos y sociolectos del idioma español hablada en el territorio mexicano. También sobresalen el dialecto del español propio de la península de Yucatán, conocido como **español yucateco** y **el español norteño** hablado en la región norte del país.*

*

> Mexican Spanish (or Mexican Spanish, es-MX)2 is the variety of
> dialects and sociolects of the Spanish language spoken in the Mexican
> territory. Also notable are the dialect of Spanish native to the
> Yucatan Peninsula, known as **Yucatecan Spanish**, and t**he Northern
> Spanish** spoken in the northern region of the country.

- 

[image]

Mapa de las variedades del español en México

> Map of the varieties of Spanish in Mexico

Para más información aconsejo que visite la página

> For more information I advise you to visit the page

Español mexicano / Mexican Spanish

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mas parecido a lo planteas, es que deseas hablar español, pero español neutro en vez de español de España, que trae sus propias jergas y acentos, en ese caso creo que se le llamaría "español latinoamericano"